# "Server Error in '/' Application" due to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.Oracle.Exception: ORA-20002: Procedure(CA_Clasic_Search)Error using Selenium

Tags: python, oracle, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am running a loop in Python 3 using Selenium that goes to a website, inputs a username + password, enters a company name in the search (Then for particular companies it crashes), and acquires some text.  Each Loop is being produced to find the revenue for a particular company, this error messages pops up for a majority of the searches but not all of them.  I find that the error happens when the search button is clicked on after the company name is inputted into the search bar.

[image: Copy of Error When Program is run, Using Firefox Browser]

```
def rev_finder(company,driver):
  page = 'https://corporateaffiliations.com/Nonsub/AccountHelp'
  driver.get(page)

  user = driver.find_element_by_id('strUserName')
  user.clear()
  user.send_keys(username)

  password = driver.find_element_by_id('strPassword')
  password.clear()
  password.send_keys(password1)

  button = driver.find_element_by_id('signOn')
  button.click()

  driver.implicitly_wait(5)

  search = driver.find_element_by_id('VAL_Name')
  search.click()
  search.send_keys(company)

  parent = driver.find_element_by_name('VAL_ParentMember')
  parent.click()

  button = driver.find_element_by_name('buttonSearch')
  button.click()

  driver.implicitly_wait(5)

  revenue = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/div").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  return revenue

def remove(string):
  string.replace("INC","").replace("Inc","").replace(".","").replace(",","")
  return string
companies = sheet['Company']
companies = companies[1:4]

revenue = []
for company in companies:
   company = remove(company)
   try:
      driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\ktorres\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\geckodriver')
      rev = rev_finder(company,driver)

   except:
      rev = 'Check Manually'
   revenue.append(rev)
```

Comment: After which line/action do you see this error exactly?

Comment: button = driver.find_element_by_name('buttonSearch')                       
button.click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
“Server Error in '/' Application”
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.Oracle.Exception: ORA-20002: Procedure(CA_Clasic_Search)Error : Execution Error of Intermedia Query
```

...implies that when attempting to change the service request owner it cannot be changed because there is an active workflow.

Your main issue is the timing of invoking `click()` on the element identified as `driver.find_element_by_name('buttonSearch')` was too early as there were some *JavaScript* / *AJAX* updating the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

You can find a detailed discussion on this error in [ORA-20002 error when try to cancel active workflow on the Service Request form (Doc ID 2045240.1)](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20E-Business%20Suite/2045240_1.html)

---

### Solution

You need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "buttonSearch"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is nothing to do with Selenium. Its an error in the web app you are testing. Selenium has done its job and found you a defect!

Comment: Ahhh Thank You, any advice on how to proceed? Would a different browser be useful

Comment: No. The web app you are testing is broken. You need to fix the issue on the page https://corporateaffiliations.com/Nonsub/AccountHelp